# Azure WebApp .NET SDK Differentiate between small, medium and large instances

Tags: .net, azure, azure-sdk-.net

When I get information about hosting plan of a webapp using `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites.Models.WebSite.Sku` property I can get following [options](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/9154888d1ddbfe84cac0d86492f4bd6b99ed06ff/src/ServiceManagement/WebSite/WebSiteManagement/Generated/Models/SkuOptions.cs): Free, Shared, Basic, Standard.

But in the portal I see that Basic plan has small, middle and large instances (B1, B2, B3).

How can I determine instance size of current hosting plan using Azure.NET SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServerFarm.[WorkerSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.management.websites.models.webspaceworkersize(v=azure.11).aspx) is the property you're looking for.  It's a property of the App Service Plan, not the individual website.